# cannot start iptables on opensuse linux

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, opensuse

i am trying to run the iptables service on opensuse linux , but unforunately its failing to activate and systemctl status message shows that its failing to find the /etc/iptables.rules file , i also tried to look for this file under the /etc/sysconfig directory but its not present even there , i tried again after creating this file manually but that didnt help either  ,  upon trying to start the service i get the message that there is no iptables service installed , even though it is .

Comment: It might help if you could provide specific commands that you ran along with the error messages that they produced. Be as specific as you can about what you have already tried.

Comment: i tried to start the iptables service but it would show that the /etc/iptables.rules files is missing ,  creating that file manually dosen't help either , the iptables service just dosent start , suselinux comes with susefirewall2 , my guess is that we just have to manipulate the susefirewall2 by writing iptable rules  and using them with the susefirewall  because that seems to be working , but everything that i have tried regarding starting the iptables service itself isnt working